# Export selenium IDE test scripts to Protractor

Tags: angularjs, selenium, xpath, protractor

I have automated some flows om my Web Application (on Angular JS) with Selenium IDE. Now after a new deployment my current test scripts have gone outdated since all the xpaths have been changed. Is there a way to Export my test cases to protractor, or any easy way to update my test cases using Selenium IDE without investing same effort and time again?

Comment: Its not advisable to use selenium ide for web apps which are changing , webdriver is the one which has to be used and avoid using xpath because they are not reliable and slow down the test performance !

Comment: Yes I never use XPATH but I have LINQ in C#.  But even in Protractor I'd still stay away from xpath for the very reason you mentioned.  Tools to convert?  How could any tool convert bad XPATHS to correct ones?